# propositional logic syntax using different symbols

Tags: propositional-calculus

Is it possible for $A\Leftrightarrow B$ to be written using only $A,B,\sim,\vee$?  If so, how?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: $it\; is\;  an\; exercise\; from \; an \; exam\; from\; university\; of\; Athens.
At\; 1st\; i\;  had\; to\; ''translate'' (A\Rightarrow B)\wedge (B\Rightarrow A),using\; only\; A,B,\wedge, \vee ,\sim .Which \; i \; did\;, thinking  (A\Rightarrow B)\wedge (B\Rightarrow A) equals\; to A\Leftrightarrow B.So,\; this \; should \; do:
(A\wedge B)\vee (\sim A\wedge \sim B)
Next\; I\; had\; to\; do\; the\; same\; thing\; using\; only\; A,B,\sim ,\vee ,.
I\; tried\; \sim (A\vee B)\vee (\sim A \vee \sim B),but\; i\; really\; believe\; something's\; not\; right...$

Comment: You should add that information (minus the italics) to the question itself. Incidentally, you're on the right track: $(A\wedge B)\vee(\sim A\wedge\sim B)$ is right. Your error was in how you translated the clauses: "$A\wedge B$" is equivalent to "$\sim(\sim A\vee\sim B)$" ("neither $A$ nor $B$ fails"), and similarly "$\sim A\wedge \sim B$" is equivalent to "$\sim (A\vee B)$" ("neither $A$ nor $B$ holds").

Comment: Okay, got it ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\neg (A\oplus B)$ is equivalent to $A\iff B$ : $$ \neg(\neg(A \lor \neg B)\lor \neg(\neg A \lor  B))$$
In general any logic function can be achieved using just $\neg$,$\lor$

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

$\lnot (\lnot A\lor \lnot B) \lor \lnot(A\lor B)$

Comment: $A\iff B$ means $(A\land B)\lor (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$; get rid of $\land$ using $C\land D\equiv \lnot(\lnot C\lor \lnot D$)